How to add text per date in CalendarView in Android Studio
I want to create individual texts per date to display some numbers that will come from a database later on. I just want to know if achieving what I have designed possible with CalendarView? Calendar design
I've seen that I cannot add textviews per date so adding them manually seems impossible? What would be some ways to implement my design?

Based on the documentation and considering the public apis of the CalendarView i can tell that it cannot be used to achieve what you're welling to implement, even it's implementation internally doesn't allow editing the content shown there as the numbers are drawn directly on the canvas.
You need to implement your own CalendarView or use an open source library for custom calendar view.
You might also consider following the same approach as in this sample code from google
